# How to style path in leaflet?

Tags: css, leaflet

I have line geometry that I've styled using the `dashArray` option. I'm trying to add a black outline to distinguish the gaps on lighter basemaps.

I tried adding a black path underneath with a heavier weight to create the outline but it seems that the gaps are transparent.

Applying the following style to the respective layers creates a white line with a black outline:

```
path = {
    color: '#ffffff',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 1
}

outline = {
    color: '#000000',
    weight: 5,
    opacity: 1
}
```

When I apply `dashArray` the bottom layer shows through:

```
path = {
    color: '#000000',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 1,
    dashArray: '5,10'
}

outline = {
    color: '#000000',
    weight: 5,
    opacity: 1
}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Leaflet path style options [here](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#path-dasharray).

EDIT: Top path is `dashArray` by itself. Second is when I overlay the `dashArray` on the wider black line (outline). Third is what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want the outline to be only of the dashes?

Comment: Adding a screenshot of what you currently have ("bottom layer shows through") and a simulation of you would like would surely help in people understanding your issue, hence to provide you with support.

Comment: see EDIT, I actually figured out an obvious solution using three layers but if there is a way to do it with one or two that would be ideal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could achieve the same effect with just 2 paths:

1. Background, continuous and wider.
2. Foreground, dashed and narrower. The background is visible through the gaps.

It is *not exactly* the same result, since if you want round caps, it is the white dashes that get them. But if you want actually square caps, as shown below, then you get the same effect:

[image: dashed path]

```js
var map = L.map("map").setView([0.4, 0], 8);
var coords = [
  [0, -1],
  [0, 1],
  [1, 1]
];

// Background continuous black stroke, wider than dashed line.
L.polyline(coords, {
  weight: 10,
  lineCap: 'square', // Optional, just to avoid round borders.
  color: 'black'
}).addTo(map);

// Foreground dashed white stroke, narrower than background.
L.polyline(coords, {
  weight: 6,
  dashArray: '5, 10',
  lineCap: 'square', // Optional, just to avoid round borders.
  color: 'white'
}).addTo(map);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet.css">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.2.0/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<div id="map" style="height: 200px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with combines the two examples using three layers placing the `dashArray` path on top of the black-outlined layer.

```
//base layer black & wider to create outline
outline = {
    color: '#000000',
    weight: 5,
    opacity: 1
}

//white line layer that will show through the transparent gaps
pathBackground = {
    color: '#ffffff',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 1
}

//dashed path is placed on top of the black-outlined white line
path = {
    color: '#000000',
    weight: 3,
    opacity: 1,
    dashArray: '5,10'
}
```